# How to make periodic event running every periodic interval in doInBackground from AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I want to make periodic event running every periodic interval in doInBackground from AsyncTask .

Like this:

```
protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
    while (true) {
            someThingToDo();
            // wait for 1000;
        }
}
```

How to do it ?

Comment: no problem, but how to do it. have you an example? Note I m newbe in Java and Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a separate class that is a subclass of the Service class.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Your primary application should can call startService and stopService to start up the background process. Theres also some other useful calls in the context class to manage the service:

Context Documentation  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29

else u can use TimerTask()

Answer (score 1):

you can use Timer or alarm service.Better to use alarm service since it can be fire when device in sleep mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out::

```
class Getphonenumber extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
     public Void doInBackground(String... p) {
      while (true) {

          someThingToDo();

       try {


        Thread.sleep(2000);


       } catch (Exception ie) {
           Log.e("Sleep", "Error: " + ie.toString());
        }
      }
    }
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think may be need used class Timer in AsyncTask.